# Listing all event Javascript

Tags: javascript, events

I'm looking for a way to list all events in javascript for a dynamic event creation or a way to check if a string is a correct event name.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Different events are valid for different elements fyi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different events are valid for different nodes.

```js
const elements = [
  'a',
  'window',
];

elements.forEach(elementName => {
  const el = document.createElement(elementName);
  console.log(`======= Events for ${elementName}:`);
  for (var prop in el) {
    if (prop.startsWith('on')) {
      console.log(prop);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't handle custom events

Comment: What do you mean by custom events? addEventListener('myevent')? I'm not certain if the OP wanted that or not

Comment: Hello, i don't want custom events, just all valid events no matter the element.

Comment: @AntoninHattabe — Custom events are valid events.

Answer (score 0):

If Chrome is an option for you, you can use its Developer Tools.

- Press **F12** to open the DevTools
- Click on the element you want to inspect in the **Elements** tab.
- Click on the **Event Listeners** tab near the *Styles* tab

You will see here every event handler attached to your element and its reference in the code.

Comment: That lists event **handlers** not events.

Comment: The question is asking about events, not event handlers.

Comment: Well, in the DevTools, the event handlers are sorted by event type, isn't it what he wanted?

Comment: The OP said "events" not "event handlers". So assuming they want what they asked for: no. They want to know all the events that are emitted.

Comment: Well, I might have misunderstood. I'll keep my answer here in case this was what he wanted.